# Firebase Android Chat Activity crashes as soon as I access it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I tried to make a chat activity using Firebase. I encountered the following error. Any help appreciated. 
Also, this is my first post. I apologize if I haven't posted this in the right section.

**ERROR**

```
Process: com.synthetech.synergyeventmanager, PID: 650
              com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert 
object of type java.lang.String to type 
com.synthetech.synergyeventmanager.MessageTemplate
```

**CODE**

**ChatActivity.java**

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Event/" + event_uid + "/Chat");

    FirebaseListAdapter<MessageTemplate> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<MessageTemplate>(
            this,
            MessageTemplate.class,
            R.layout.message_template,
            databaseReference.orderByKey()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, MessageTemplate msg, int position) {

            TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatMessage);
            TextView user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatUser);

            String chatMessageFetcher;
            String chatUserFetcher;

            chatMessageFetcher = msg.getMessage();
            chatUserFetcher = msg.getUser();

            message.setText(chatMessageFetcher);
            user.setText(chatUserFetcher);

        }
    };

    chatList.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

**MessageTemplate.java**

```
public class MessageTemplate {

String message;
String user;


public MessageTemplate() {
}

public MessageTemplate(String message, String user) {
    this.message = message;
    this.user = user;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}


public String getUser() {
    return user;
  }
}
```

**On-click method to push message**

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == sendButton){
        String event_uid;
        String chat;
        event_uid = eventuid_txt.getText().toString();
        chat = message.getText().toString();
        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        MessageTemplate msg = new MessageTemplate(chat, 
firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
        DatabaseReference chatRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Event/"+event_uid+"/Chat");
        chatRef.push().setValue(msg);
        message.setText("");
    }
}
```

**JSON File Structure**

```
{
  "Event" : {
    "Aseem_SDp3G2wfbBOGXsfPFWQBfVvj7wo2" : {
      "Chat" : {
         "
        "message" : "Hey there! ",
        "time" : 1492502099191,
        "user" : "aseem@synergy.io"
               }
   }
}
```

**Please note**: I've changed the code. The message that you see up there was added earlier. I've added **.push()** method now. Hence, the structure would change once the code is up and running. 
The current structure would be something like this-

```
Event
    -Event_uid
        -Chat
            -Chat_uid
                -message
                -time
                -user
```

Comment: Can you also show the part where you push the messages to firebase?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON (as text, no screenshot) at `databaseReference`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I've added the JSON file structure and the on-click method. Please, let me know what's wrong with the code. I'd be grateful!